# CShellManager Failed Initialisation

Tags: c++, mfc

Hy,

My configuration is:

- Windows 10 Visual studio 2019
- I used MFC and c++.

I have created a CDialogEx where i use CMFCShellTreeCtrl and CMFCShellListCtrl.

I have included the headers: afxwinappex.h and afxshellmanager.h

My application is started with

```
BOOL CtestsApp::InitInstance()
{
...
 CWinAppEx *pApp;
 pApp = DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST(CWinAppEx, AfxGetApp);
 pApp->InitShellManager();
...
}
```

When I trace through InitShellManager() function, I have a violation see below

```
BOOL CWinAppEx::InitShellManager()
{
    /* afxShellManager is NULL */
    if (afxShellManager != NULL) 
    {
        return (TRUE);
    }

    afxShellManager = new CShellManager;
    m_bShellManagerAutocreated = TRUE; 
    /* ==> Problem violation write */
    return (TRUE);
}
```

Why?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [what's on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as how to create [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Adding all these details allows others to reproduce your problem and help you effectively.

Comment: Yes, this question needs editing... "Violation write" ? What is the exception message ? Have you tried setting a watch ? and it would help if you provide the declaration of m_bShellManagerAutocreated. Where is it declared.. is it a property.. maybe that property has a Setter..

Comment: `pApp = DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST(CWinAppEx, AfxGetApp);` This doesn't even compile. Please post *real* code. And if it *did* compile it would still be wrong on several levels. Your `CtestsApp` should be deriving from `CWinAppEx` and in that case you don't need any cast and, in fact, any `pApp` pointer since you are in a member function of the app already. Just call `InitShellManager();`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your's response. I have change CWinApp to CWinAppEx ans call InitShellManager();.

All Is good

Comment: There's no mention in the question, that you were using `CWinApp` at all. To make this useful [update](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63072634/edit) your question and include a [mcve].